# Error while sending data with Game Center

Tags: ios, swift2, nsdata, game-center

I'm trying to get my application to send data to the other player that is in the match. I keep getting this error:

> Error Domain=Foundation._GenericObjCError Code=0 "(null)".

My code for sending data is below. I've tried sending strings, and custom objects as well and get the same error.

```
    var isReady: Int = 1
    let data = NSData(bytes: &isReady, length: sizeof(Int))

    do {
        try match.sendData(data, toPlayers: match.players, dataMode: .Reliable)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error trying to send object: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: I solved my problem, I was setting the delegate incorrectly.